# Problems with rendering a component on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to display a page within the Home page, so to speak, by clicking a link in a navigation bar that then displays a "square" of information without leaving the Home page. This is my Home:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class Home extends Component {

    var Music = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h2> BBB </h2>
                </div>
            );

        }
    });


    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Home' id='Home'>
                <div id='musicMenu'>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="music"><Link to="/music">Music</Link></li>
                        <li id="shows"><Link to="/shows">Shows</Link></li>
                        <li id="collections"><Link to="/collections">Collections</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

import App from 'views/App';
import Home from 'views/Home';
import About from 'views/About';
import Cart from 'views/webcart';
import Music from 'views/music';
import Shows from 'views/shows';
import Collections from 'views/collections';



ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={ hashHistory }>
    <Route path='/' component={ App }>
      <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
      <Route path='about' component={ About } />
      <Route path='Cart' component={ Cart } />
      <Route path='music' component={ Music } />
      <Route path='shows' component={ Shows } />
      <Route path='collections' component={ Collections } />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app') // eslint-disable-line
);
```

The error I'm getting in Webpack is

```
 ERROR in ./js/views/Home.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected
```

and points to `var Music`. How can I fix this error? Also, is this the best way to do this or can anyone recommend a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a `var` within the `Home` class. That's not allowed in `JS`. Move it outside just below the `imports`.

Also the square you want to display is this component?

```
<div>
   <h2> BBB </h2>
</div>
```

Add a CSS class called `.invisible` like this

```
.invisible{
   display:none;
}
```

And then in the home `state` do something like

```
this.state = {
    showSquare:false
}
```

And in the `render`

```
   <div className='Home' id='Home'>
            <div className={this.state.showSquare?'':'invisible'}>
              <h2> BBB </h2>
            </div>
            <div id='musicMenu'>
                 <ul>
                   <li id="music"><Link to="/music">Music</Link></li>
                   <li id="shows"><Link to="/shows">Shows</Link></li>
                   <li id="collections"><Link to="/collections">Collections</Link></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
   </div>
```

What this does is make the square `invisible` when `this.state.showSquare` is false. Then in the navigation bar add a click handler which changes the `state.showSquare`

```
<li onClick={this.toggleShowSquare}>Show Square</li>
```

where `toggleShowSquare()` is

```
toggleShowSquare(){
   this.setState((prevState)=>({showSquare:!prevState.showSquare}))
}
```

Remember to do a

`this.toggleShowSquare = this.toggleShowSquare.bind(this)` in the `constructor`

**EDIT**: Replying to comment.
For multiple divs do this

```
this.state = {
        showSquareOne:false,
        showSquareTwo:false
   }
```

Then have the divs like this

```
<div className={this.state.showSquareOne?'':'invisible'}></div>
<div className={this.state.showSquareTwo?'':'invisible'}></div>
```

The `li` elements like this

```
<li onClick={()=>this.toggleShowSquare('showSquareOne')}>Show Square One</li>
<li onClick={()=>this.toggleShowSquare('showSquareTwo')}>Show Square Two</li>
```

And the function like this

```
 toggleShowSquare(property){
       this.setState((prevState)=>({[property]:!prevState[property]}))
    }
```

Comment: I can't get this to work..check out how I tried to apply your suggestions https://pastebin.com/pt5eKvKV. It gives me the following errors `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showSquare' of null`, but I don't understand how to give value to that null..and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$rbdzmecwll' of null`.

Comment: `this.state = {showSquare:false;}` needs to be there in the `constructor` below the `super()`. If the `state` is not initialized it won't work. That's why it's returning `null` as the `state.showSquare` is not there. Also add the `<li onClick={this.toggleShowSquare}>Show Square</li>` in the `<ul>` so you can see it working and put some content in that `div` so you can actually see the change.

Comment: If I want to use toggleShowSquare with another li, how can I change the className for another div?

Comment: Check out the edit in the original answer. It's pretty straightforward. If it's not clear do let me know. I'll explain better.